# Finding the MLE of $\alpha$ from the following.

Tags: statistics

Given: $f(x) = e^{-(x-\alpha)}$ for $x \ge \alpha$ and $0$ for $x < \alpha$.

Attempt: $L(\alpha) = \prod_{i=1}^n e^{\alpha - x_i}$ and so $l(\alpha) = \log[L(\alpha)] = \cdots = n \alpha - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$. So then $l'(\hat{\alpha}) = n = 0$. I then get stuck. What errors am I making?

Answer (score 1):

Write the density as $f(x) = e^{-(x-a)}1[x \geq \alpha]$,
where $1[\cdot]$ is the indicator function.

The likelihood function is then
$$
L(\alpha) = \exp(-n(\bar{x} - \alpha))\prod_{i=1}^{n}1[x_{i} \geq \alpha]
= \exp(-n\bar{x})e^{n\alpha}1[x_{(1)} \geq \alpha]
$$
where $x_{(1)} = \min\{x_{1},\ldots,x_{n} \}$. Then, we can clearly see that 
the likelihood function is positive and increasing for $\alpha \leq x_{(1)}$ and
then equals $0$ for $\alpha > x_{(1)}$. Hence, the value of $\alpha$ which
maximizes the likelihood is $\hat{\alpha} = x_{(1)}$.